# Speech Activity Detection- Adhoc Problem with multi source sounds(birds,trees,heavy air) and how to eliminate them completely

Tags: speech-recognition, dsp-core, voice

Here i will first try to put my application agenda

> Typically i am sampling at 8Khz rate and filtering speech components using a BPF(digital)
>   now i have got the 0-4Khz components in which essentially <250Hz are not speech so i will eliminate them also
>   now i am trying to find out entropy of frame and trying to mark respective frames as voice or non voice if they belong to band 250<=f<=3750 Hz

so now the problem is while i was doing this at my realtime application side there also non human sounds like birds sound or a ringing of a bell which again fall in to the frequency band i am flagging as speech

so this causes a false alarm of speech even in case of bird sound and bell ringing how to really over come this problem

what else i can try to do for effectvie speech activity detection

Comment: I suggest you to remove aliasing from the title of your question, since this phenomenon does not seem to be involved here.

Comment: if its not aliasing then what it is aliasing is when a high freq(greater than nyquist ) are been sampled, the components appear in existing band after the phenomenon of aliasing isn't it ? same seems to happening here a diff freq bird sound is appearing in speech region obviously looks aliasing for me

Comment: You are correct about your definition of aliasing but this is not what is happening here. Birds or bell sounds simply do have frequency components in the 250-3750 Hz band.

Answer (score 2):

This is not aliasing this is not any phenomenon, there are number of birds whose vocal fall in speech range even a frog vocal falls in speech range so essentially a training based speech detection is required to classify whether a given frame is speech or a non speech

one such implementation is shown here

[Speech Discrimination based on multi-scale spectro-temporal modulations](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1621204)